# How To use multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id  day  line    color   
1   1    1       white          
2   1    2       orange    
3   2    1       White       
4   2    2       Orange     
5   2    3       White
```

I'm trying to get a result :

```
day line  color         
1   1,2    white,orange 
2   1,2,3    white,orange,white 

SELECT day
     , line
     , color  from name_table 
  GROUP 
    BY day 
 ORDER 
    BY day ASC
```

does not work for me, any help

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: check out group_concat()

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT for that purpose

> ```
> CREATE TABLE name_table 
>     (`id` int, `day` int, `line` int, `color` varchar(6))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO name_table 
>     (`id`, `day`, `line`, `color`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 1, 1, 'white'),
>     (2, 1, 2, 'orange'),
>     (3, 2, 1, 'White'),
>     (4, 2, 2, 'Orange'),
>     (5, 2, 3, 'White')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT day
>      , GROUP_CONCAT(line ORDER BY  line ASC) kine
>      , GROUP_CONCAT(color ORDER BY  line ASC) color  
>   FROM name_table 
>   GROUP 
>     BY day 
>  ORDER 
>     BY day ASC
> ```
>
> ```
> day | kine  | color             
> --: | :---- | :-----------------
>   1 | 1,2   | white,orange      
>   2 | 1,2,3 | White,Orange,White
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=77659aa8a2e4fade1baab2b34ba4fcd0)*